# StringBuilder удалить определённый символ в строке

Tags: java, строки

Без регулярки, и не заменить его пробелом, а именно удалить.

```java
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(string);
char ch = 43;
stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(???);
```

Я не знаю под каким индексом в строке может быть знак "+"

Comment: [Отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1317656/edit) ваш вопрос, добавьте информацию о том, сколько раз в строке может встречаться символ `+`, нужно ли удалять все символы `+` или только первый (последний).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы найти индекс определенного символа:

```java
int index = stringBuilder.indexOf(String.valueOf(ch));
```

Далее, удалим этот символ по индексу, если такой индекс был найден:

```java
if (index != -1) {
    stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(index);
}
```

Обратите внимание, что `indexOf` вернет индекс первого совпадения. Соответственно, будет удален только первый попавшийся символ `+`.